# Poner checkbox a la izquierda y label derecha problema con espacios

Tags: html, css, css3

Necesito poner el checbox tal cual esta a la izquierda pero que el label se quede a la derecha pegado sin esos extraños saltos de lineas gigantes ni que continue el texto por debajo del checkbox
SIN USAR FLEX NI GRID

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
main aside #form {
    margin-top: 55px;
  }
  main aside #form span {
    display: block;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 3.28px;
    color: #08A6E4;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  main aside #form input {
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #95989A;
    font-size: 20px;
    outline: none;
  }
  main aside #form #politicas {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  main aside #form #politicas input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
    color: #08a6e4;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 30%;
  }
  main aside #form #politicas label {
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #707070;
    width: 50%;
  }
  main aside #form button {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div id="politicas">
                        <input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">
                        <label for="check">
                            I hereby give consent for my personal data included in my application to be processed for the purposes of the recruitment process under the European Parliament’s and Council of the European Union Regulation on the Protection of Natural Persons as of 27 April 2016, with regard to the processing of personal data and on the free movement of such data, and repealing Directive 95/46/EC (Data Protection Directive)
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con [css grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) sale muy fácil, por ejemplo puedes crear una clase que se llame .checkitem y se la agregas al div id="politicas"

```
 .checkitem{
    display: grid;
    gap: 11px;
    grid-template-columns: 39px 1fr;
  }
```

Aquí cree una grilla con 2 columnas, la primera de 39px y la segunda con todo lo que sobre de width (100%-39px), además le di un espacio entre columnas  (gap) de 11px

```css
main aside #form {
    margin-top: 55px;
  }
  main aside #form span {
    display: block;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 3.28px;
    color: #08A6E4;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  main aside #form input {
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #95989A;
    font-size: 20px;
    outline: none;
  }
  main aside #form #politicas {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  main aside #form #politicas input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
    color: #08a6e4;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 30%;
  }
  main aside #form #politicas label {
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #707070;
    width: 50%;
  }
  main aside #form button {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .checkitem{
    display: grid;
    gap: 11px;
    grid-template-columns: 39px 1fr;
  }
```

```html
<div id="politicas" class="checkitem">
                        <input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">
                        <label for="check">
                            I hereby give consent for my personal data included in my application to be processed for the purposes of the recruitment process under the European Parliament’s and Council of the European Union Regulation on the Protection of Natural Persons as of 27 April 2016, with regard to the processing of personal data and on the free movement of such data, and repealing Directive 95/46/EC (Data Protection Directive)
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

#### Update, solución sin grid ni flex

```css
.checkitem > label{
display: inline-block;
    
     width: calc(100% - 52px);
     vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkitem > input[type=checkbox]{
       display: inline-block;
   width: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;    
}
```

```html
<div id="politicas" class="checkitem">
<input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">
<label for="check">
    I hereby give consent for my personal data included in my application to be processed for the purposes of the recruitment process under the European Parliament’s and Council of the European Union Regulation on the Protection of Natural Persons as of 27 April 2016, with regard to the processing of personal data and on the free movement of such data, and repealing Directive 95/46/EC (Data Protection Directive)
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: es que en la version mobile no puedo usar ni flex ni grid aunque si usare grid como recomendaste para la desktop. ¿como haría sin usara flex ni grid?

Comment: @FranyxD Actualicé para una solución si grid ni flex

Comment: pense que los vertical align estaban ya en desuso no recomendado, pero ha funcionado muy bien gracias!!

Comment: @FranyxD Están en desuso pero no deprecados (que es distinto). Se ocupan menos, porque justamente con grid y flex ya no se necesitan, pues estos traen la propiedad align

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias, aprendi con esta respuesta